# How would a Hornet's Nest grenade work?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

A hornet's nest grenade is ammunition for a (usually 40mm) grenade launcher that fires several smaller rounds instead of the grenade itself.

What stats would this kind of weapon have? It's not a series of shots like auto-fire, but rather the equivalent of 4-10 sidearms firing simultaneously, so I appreciate any input on this conundrum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Armory book lists examples of Grenade ammunitions on page 106. The Buckshot entry of that table seems to come closest to what you want it to do. Important to know is that grenades fired through a grenade launcher add extra successes to the attack roll (almost all other weapons give extra dice to roll when attacking).

Example:

- **12 gauge** : this is what the shotgun from the core book uses (cross-checking with Armory book p88). Normally this adds four extra dice on the attack roll. If we make a hornet nest grenade with a 12 gauge it would then be considered to have a Force of four. This translates to four extra successes on the attack roll. We went from rolling four extra dice, to four extra successes on the attack roll. Quite the power boost.
- **.22 Caliber** : the normal .22 adds two dice and has Armor Piercing 1. If we load this into a hornet grenade I would rule that this gives two extra successes on the attack roll (the Armor Piercing receives the same). I'm deliberately ignoring the fact that you can fire ten .22 at the same time. I think that the powerboost of getting two extra successes instead of rolling dice is enough.